# Bitmap Memory Leak?

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, recycle

I've been making a menu system that mimics ViewFlipper except I personally reset the images and text within the RootView myself, trying to avoid Bitmap related OOM. All was going well until yesterday when I realized after a few restarts, and subsequent view changes, I'd get the Bitmap Exceeds VM budget.. or something alike. I started allocation tracker and tried to see what wasn't being dumped, and found these calls my source of trouble:

```
_stars.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_1));
_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_1); 
_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
```

This obviously isn't all the code, but it's where the tracker is pointing me for the **MANY** allocations like this:

```
258 72  android.graphics.BitmapFactory$Options  1 android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
481 68  android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable 1 android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
482 52  android.graphics.Paint  1   android.graphics.Bitmap createBitmap    
479 52  android.graphics.Paint 1 android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState
255 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.BitmapFactory      
254 36  android.graphics.Canvas 1   android.graphics.Bitmap createBitmap    
250 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.Bitmap nativeCreate    
123 36  android.graphics.Bitmap 1   android.graphics.BitmapFactory
```

What I'm wondering, **is this normal? Or do I have a leak somewhere?** There are at least **10-20** of each of these in my allocations after the test, and inevitably I hit OOM eventually. Not sure how to take care of this other than using a Bitmap variable, and then Bitmap.recycle() possibly, but that involves checking if the view is still being used and possibly recycling at the wrong time; hence I'm not a fan. I'm more just looking for a way to kill all of these allocations every time I exit view.**(already tried setting the controls to null onPause() & onDestroy(), hoping they'd release the references to the bitmaps, and thus be able to GC them to NO AVAIL)**

**[edit]**

I've since read [here](http://blog.pseudoblue.com/2010/08/15/android-bitmaps-and-memory-leaks/) that Drawables get handled as necessary when your activity is finished. So therefore I shouldn't have to call recycle on them should I? As for the size of the single Bitmap, it is just one image ***(480w x 720h (x4bpp/8))/1024 = ~169KB***, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Exceeding the VM budget doesn't necessarily mean that there is a leak. I've cause the same issue by trying to load a single bitmap that was just way to big. Also, if you remove the reference, it may not GC right away anyway and you might still run out of memory.
You may need to call `.Recycle` somehow, as I don't think there is a way to force GC run when you want it to, but `Recycle` will free native references held by the bitmap when you run it so you don't have to wait for a GC.

Comment: I've added some edits that address what you're saying without doing it right here.